# Illuminate\Queue\MaxAttemptsExceededException in laravel in shared hosting

Tags: php, queue, laravel-8, jobs, shared-hosting

I have used shared hosting in hostinger. Queue Job every time failed or remains running. I have tried every thing but didnot get any solution.

In terminal after running php artisan queue:work The procees killed then it will gives failed with the error:

Illuminate\Queue\MaxAttemptsExceededException: App\Jobs\ImportJob has been attempted too many times or run too long. The job may have previously timed out.
First the program calls the livewire class Import then ImportJOb the ProductImport (Note it works perfect in localhost but it has issue in server)

**Import.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use App\Jobs\ImportJob;
use Modules\Product\Entities\Product;
use Modules\Product\Entities\Years;
use Modules\Product\Entities\Glasses;
use Modules\Product\Entities\Parts;
use Modules\Product\Entities\Bodystyles;
use Modules\Product\Entities\Models;
use Modules\Product\Entities\Makers;
use Modules\Product\Entities\Features;
use Modules\Product\Entities\BodystylesModels;
use Livewire\Component;
use Livewire\WithFileUploads;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Bus;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

class Import extends Component
{
    use WithFileUploads;

    public $batchId;
    public $importFile;
    public $importing = false;
    public $importFilePath;
    public $importFinished = false;

    public function import()
    {
        $this->validate([
            'importFile' => 'required',
        ]);

        // Product::query()->truncate();
        // Years::query()->truncate();
        // Makers::query()->truncate();
        // Models::query()->truncate();
        // Bodystyles::query()->truncate();
        // Glasses::query()->truncate();
        // Parts::query()->truncate();
        // Features::query()->truncate();
        

        $this->importing = true;
        $this->importFilePath = $this->importFile->store('imports');

        $batch = Bus::batch([
            new ImportJob($this->importFilePath),
        ])->dispatch();

        $this->batchId = $batch->id;
    }

    public function getImportBatchProperty()
    {
        if (!$this->batchId) {
            return null;
        }

        return Bus::findBatch($this->batchId);
    }

    public function updateImportProgress()
    {
        $this->importFinished = $this->importBatch->finished();

        if ($this->importFinished) {
            Storage::delete($this->importFilePath);
            $this->importing = false;
        }
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.import');
    }
}
```

**Import Job.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Bus\Batchable;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use App\Imports\ProductImport;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldBeUnique;

class ImportJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Batchable, Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $uploadFile;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($uploadFile)
    {
        $this->uploadFile = $uploadFile;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        Excel::import(new ProductImport, $this->uploadFile);
    }

    /**
     * The job failed to process.
     *
     * @param  Exception  $exception
     * @return void
     */
    public function failed(Exception $exception)
    {
        dd($exception);
    }
}
```

**ProductImport.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Imports;

use Modules\Product\Entities\Product;
use Modules\Product\Entities\Years;
use Modules\Product\Entities\Glasses;
use Modules\Product\Entities\Parts;
use Modules\Product\Entities\Bodystyles;
use Modules\Product\Entities\Models;
use Modules\Product\Entities\Makers;
use Modules\Product\Entities\Features;
use Modules\Product\Entities\BodystylesModels;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadingRow;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithBatchInserts;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithChunkReading;

class ProductImport implements ToModel, WithHeadingRow, WithChunkReading
{
    private $users;

    public function __construct()
    {
        
        // $this->users = User::all(['id', 'name'])->pluck('id', 'name');
    }

    public function model(array $row)
    {
        
        // MakersFeatures::
        
        $year= Years::where('years_name', trim($row['year'],''))->first();
        
        $make= Makers::where('makers_name', trim($row['make'],''))->first();
        $model= Models::where('models_name', trim($row['model'],''))->first();
        $style= Bodystyles::where('bodystyles_name', trim($row['style'],''))->first();
        $glass= Glasses::where('glasses_name', trim($row['glass'],''))->first();
        $part= Parts::where('parts_name', trim($row['partnumber'],''))->first();
        $feature= Features::where('features_name', trim($row['feature'],''))->first();

        if($year==null)
        {
            $year= Years::create(['years_name'=> trim($row['year'],'')]);
            
        }
        if($make==null)
        {
            $make= Makers::create(['makers_name'=> trim($row['make'],'')]);
        }
    
        if($model==null)
        {
            $model= Models::create(
                [
                    'models_name'=> trim($row['model'],''),
                    'makers_id'=>$make->id
    
                ]);
        }

        if($style==null)
        {
            $style= Bodystyles::create(['bodystyles_name'=> trim($row['style'],'')]);
        }

        if($glass==null)
        {
               
            $glass= Glasses::create(['glasses_name'=>trim($row['glass'],'')]);
        }

        if($part==null)
        {
               
            $part= Parts::create(['parts_name'=>trim($row['partnumber'],'')]);

        }
        if($feature==null)
        {
            $feature= Features::create([
                'features_name'=>trim($row['feature'],''),
                'glasses_id'=>$glass->id
            ]);
        }

        

        $f=
        [
            'years_id'=>$year->id,
            'makers_id'=>$make->id, 
            'models_id'=>$model->id, 
            'bodystyles_id'=>$style->id, 
            'glasses_id'=>$glass->id, 
            'part_id'=>$part->id,
            'product_part_number'=>trim($row['partnumber'],''),
            'product_price'=>trim($row['sale_price'],''),
            'features_id'=> $feature->id
        ];
        
        // $d= MakersFeatures::create($f);
  
        return new Product($f);
    }

    public function chunkSize(): int
    {
        return 2000;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would try to figure out *why* the job is failing. The queue keeps retrying the job when it fails, until it runs out of retries. Fix the original failure, and it will fix the MaxAttempts issue. Check your Laravel logs in `storage/logs` for any information on the failure.

Comment: yes I have already check the logs it has always same error

Comment: local.ERROR: App\Jobs\ImportJob::failed(): Argument #1 ($exception) must be of type App\Jobs\Exception, Illuminate\Queue\MaxAttemptsExceededException given

Comment: this is the error

Comment: Can you post `App\Jobs\ImportJob`? The issue is coming from there somewhere

Comment: I have added the all 3 files when I press import it goes to all these 3 to upload the data

Comment: If the job takes while, you may want to add a higher [timeout](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queues#timeout) to the job